# How to insert single rows to a dataframe based on specific value on a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to add the row present in the "pixels" dataframe to the "with_key" dataframe where value of a cell in with_key["Key"] column is equal to "2"

```
pixels = pd.DataFrame()
with_key = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Key"])

keys = []

for x in range(5):
    key = x
    keys.append(key)
with_key["Key"] = keys
print(with_key)

arr=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,255,0,0,0])

pixels = pd.DataFrame(arr)
pixels = pixels.T

pixels.head()
```

Comment: please provide sample data and your expected output. It's a little unclear as to where the row needs to be added.

Comment: Hello, i have updated my problem.. would you be kind enough to have a look?

Comment: expected output still not clear to me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax

```py
import pandas as pd
with_key = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Key"])

keys = []


for x in range(5):
    key = x
    keys.append(key)
# with_key["Key"] = keys
for key in keys:
    if key == 1:
        with_key = with_key.append({'Key': key}, ignore_index=True)

print(with_key)
```

You can refer pandas `append` documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) which has examples of how you can insert a row into an existing dataframe

Comment: Hello, i have updated my problem.. would you be kind enough to have a look?